# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap on ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Web API application that will run dtsx files expected to be on the same server, but I am getting error below:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. The system cannot
> find the file specified. File name:
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Below code gives the error:

```
Application app = new Application();
```

Please assist

- I have selected the project from solution explorer, changed the platform target under 'build' in 'properties to x64 which is the OS I am testing with from 'Any CPU'
- I have downloaded SqlServer 2014 to match version 12.0.0.0 that the Application is trying to use. The previous version is 15.0.0.0

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Integration Services installed on your web server, and does the web application user have permissions to use SSIS? SSIS calls in your code are (or at least previously were) dependent on local SSIS files.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Sql Server Express which doesn't support SSIS. I have switched to Sql Server Developer and installed SSIS. I also added Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll from Reference Manager. The error is gone